# The required MSI package D:\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise\x64\setup\.' doesn't exist error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the setup file on the D: drive, and I am installing the SQL 2012 enterprise on the C: drive. Every time I try to install it, it gives the following error

### TITLE: Message Details

**The required MSI package D:\Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise\x64\setup.' doesn't exist**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXrO.png)

I tried to copy/paste the sql_engine_core_inst from the root directory where I have the setup files, to C: windows installer and renamed it to 9bcac.msi as said in the link below on social.msdn.mic forum, nothing helped.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2aa6136b-9ccd-4c97-a6d3-cbe408c38228/sql-server-2008-service-pack-1-installation-problem

Comment: Is your machine a 32 bit machine and are you are trying to install a 64 bit installer?

Comment: @ArunGeorge its 64 bit machine.